# Django Rest Framework extending user model, how to create user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to extend the user model with attributes that are specific to the application, in this case I am simply substituting them with `extA` and `extB`. I have made a model to extend the user model and I have created a simple serializer for that model. Now I'm not sure how to create the user with the extra fields.

**models.py**

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    extA = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    extB = models.IntegerField(null=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def handle_user_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserDetails.objects.create(user=instance)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'extA', 'extB')
```

**views.py**

```
class UserDetailsView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, id, format=None):
        data = User.objects.get(id)
        serializer_class = UserDetailsSerializer
        return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

I have been creating users via the shell. Like this:
`user = User.objects.create_user('John', 'john@email.com', 'pass')`. This works really well but I'm not sure how to create a `UserDetailsView` object and save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create UserDetails in your view

```
 user = User.objects.get(id=id)
 UserDetails.objects.create(id=user.id,user=user,extA=your_val_1,extB=your_val_2)
```

And then you should be able to refer it as user.userdetails.extA, user.userdetails.extB

Comment: Running this command in the shell I am getting: `IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: app_userdetails.user_id`. Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: It means the id you're providing already exists. Delete it with UserDetails.objects.get(id=id).delete() or provide an id that is not there